# Найти элемент на экране по лейблу соседнего элемента

Tags: swift, xcode, ui

Есть такое дерево элементов.

[image: doom]

Их может быть несколько таких на экране. Мне нужно активировать свитч расположенный в этом дереве у конкретного мне лейбла в StaticText. Прикрепляться по switches.element(boundBy: ) не могу так как на экране может быть несколько свитчей и не всегда приходит их одинаковое кол-во и из-за этого тесты валятся. Может можно как-то через NSPredicate достучаться до этого свитча зная лейбл у staticText или ещё как-то. Заранее благодарю за ответ

Пример экрана с такими элементами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У элементов есть теги, вы можете выставить тег и затем обратиться к нужному элементу по тегу.

Например:

```
label.tag = 2
if let foundView = view.viewWithTag(2) { ... }
```